# Pass variable from SASS mixin to CSS Value

Tags: css, sass, css-transforms, string-interpolation, scss-mixins

How can we pass the value of variable `$name` to a CSS value.

Our `$name` variable = `"rotateX"` however `transform: $name( 360deg );` doesn't seem to output `transform: rotateX( 360deg );`

Even if we use interpolation:

This SCSS

```
@mixin rotate( $name ) {
  animation-name: $name;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  
  @keyframes #{ $name } {
    100% {
      transform: #{ $name } ( 360deg );
    }
  }
}

.rotate-x {
  @include rotate( $name: rotateX );
}
```

Outputs this CSS:

```
.rotate-x {
  animation-name: rotateX;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
@keyframes rotateX {
  100% {
    transform: rotateX 360deg; } }
```

For some reason the parenthesis are gone around `360deg` value breaking the entire CSS rule.

### How can we properly add `transform: rotateX( 360deg )` where `rotateX` is a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be the best solution. But it'll solve your problem.
Try with the below code.

```
@mixin rotate( $name ) {
  animation-name: $name;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  
  @keyframes #{ $name } {
    100% {
      transform: #{ $name }#{"("}360deg#{")"};
    }
  }
}

.rotate-x {
  @include rotate( $name: rotateX );
}
```

Comment: Yes. Wow it works, but how? What do the quotes do?

Comment: In sass/scss when you write variables and parenthesis altogether it considers that an arithmetic operation and thus ignores it. That is what I understand, might be a different issue though.

Anyway if my answer solves your problem, can you accept it as the final answer to your question by clicking the `tick mark`?